# Apache POI How to modify excel cell without loading whole excel (xlsx file)

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Folks,

We have one requirement related to scalability for excel update.

e.g. We have Excel work book with 10 work sheets each is having huge amount of data.

Now what we want to do is replace one of the CELL in one of the sheet with 'NEW VALUE'

But with Apache POI we understood we have to load entire 'Work book' even if we have to modify data in one of the excel sheets. This is consuming huge memory and is not acceptable.

Is there any CELL level read write(immediate flush) facility or API for excel.

Comment: `.xls` or `.xlsx` - they're different

Comment: it is .xlsx file (excel 2010)

Answer (score 1):

An XLSX file is actually a ZIP file containing multiple XML files.

You could extract the contents (but keep the folder structure intact), change only the XML file you want, compress it back, and replace the original.

Comment: Raj Any JAVA API to get the XML part of .xlsx and then merge it back.